# Why Javascript Codes Don't Run in user control?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, updatepanel

I'm working on a project that contains a single page (home.aspx).

Home.aspx contains a ScriptManager and an UpdatePanel — a div with some LinkButtons that load related UserControls.

Some of those user controls contains javascript. My problem is that the javascript doesn't run on time (after LinkButton click or UC loads).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your script is registered with the [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the user controls have JS inline, it will not run; JavaScript added by setting the innerHTML of an element (which is what `UpdatePanel` does) does not run.

As Rick Schott mentions, if the user controls register their script with the `ScriptManager` - either by including `asp:ScriptReference`s in their `ScriptManagerProxy` or by adding it from their codebehind using one of the `ScriptManager.Register*` variants - it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For your Answers , But I had examined This solutions .
User Controls Haven't Script Manager , Script Manager Placed in Home.aspx .
I use both Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock , Page.RegisterStartupScript , ...
But These don't work properly . Java script Codes in UC are in Script tag in top of UC Like Below :

```
                   function pageLoad() {
   $addHandler($get("<%=Button2.ClientID%>"), 'click', cp);
```

}
                       function cp() {

```
  /* Do shomthing ... */
```

}

//*################ END OF JAVASCRIPT CODES

In above JS Code Button2 is a asp Button placed in UC .
I Find A New Thing today : If add defer='defer' in above Script tag it runs like a charm!
But this solution is for IE(ONLY) , So this isn't the best solution .
What Can i do more ...?

Comment: ScriptManager.Register* is static.  If you user control is in a page that has a ScriptManager(required with an UpdatePanel) then it will find it.